# drawpath outside ondraw function android

Tags: android

I am using  the drawpath function outside the ondraw function .I am calling this in my own function where I am calculating the screen co-ordinates.But draw path is not paiinting anything.

Is it true that the drawpath is functional only inside ondraw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you want to draw a `Path` you have to use a `Canvas` which you can only use in the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method. However it is possible to call you method from within the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method like this

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    drawPath(canvas);
}

public void drawPath(Canvas canvas) {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(4, -10);
    path.lineTo(20, 0);
    path.lineTo(-9, 0);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

see also [How to use canvas in your android apps](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-2) for more information on `Path`

Comment: Thanks that solved one part of my issue.The other issue is that before drawing the path  I need to calculate the  points that fall on this path using equations of trajectory  which means I cannnot call the draw path on ondraw.Can you please suggest me alternative to it.

Comment: as I got the confirmation for the cause of issue from you, I accept your answer.I solved the later part of my issue by calling invalidate after calculating the points.